# VBA - Apply Filter Across Multiple Sheets if Column Header is a Match

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that renames certain headers, deletes certain columns and inserts a row on specific sheets.

I need to apply a filter across the sheets **IF** the header is found on the sheet.

The `with wkbk1` statement has 2 `for loops`, the second loop I just copied from the first one and attempted to apply the filter.

Here is the code:

```
Sub ManipulateSheets()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, ws4 As Worksheet
    Dim a As Long, w As Long
    Dim keepCols As Variant
    Dim wkbk1 As Workbook

    Set wkbk1 = Workbooks("testWorkbook.xlsm")

    'Set sheets to be used in each workbook
    Set ws2 = wkbk1.Sheets("mySheet")
    Set ws3 = wkbk1.Sheets("hisSheet")
    Set ws4 = wkbk1.Sheets("herSheet")

    keepCols = Array("Employee Number", "Status")
    filterCols = Array("Status")

    wkbk1.Activate

    ws2.Activate

    Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert

    Range("A1").Value = "Employee Number"

    ws3.Activate

    Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert

    Range("A1").Value = "Employee Number"

    ws4.Activate

    Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert

    Range("A1").Value = "Employee Number"

    For Each ws1 In wkbk1.Sheets

        ws1.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Replace What:="USERID", Replacement:="Employee Number", Lookat:=xlWhole
        ws1.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Replace What:="STATUS", Replacement:="Status", Lookat:=xlWhole
        ws1.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Replace What:="USER_ID", Replacement:="Employee Number", Lookat:=xlWhole
        ws1.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Replace What:="USER-ID", Replacement:="Employee Number", Lookat:=xlWhole
        ws1.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Replace What:="USER_STATUS", Replacement:="Status", Lookat:=xlWhole
        ws1.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Replace What:="HR_STATUS", Replacement:="Status", Lookat:=xlWhole

    Next ws1

    With wkbk1

        For w = 1 To .Worksheets.count

            With Worksheets(w)

                For a = .Columns.count To 1 Step -1

                    If UBound(Filter(keepCols, .Cells(1, a), True, vbTextCompare)) < 0 Then _
                            .Columns(a).EntireColumn.Delete

                Next a

            End With

        Next w

        For w = 1 To .Worksheets.count

            With Worksheets(w)

                For a = .Columns.count To 1 Step -1

                    If UBound(Filter(filterCols, .Cells(1, a), True, vbTextCompare)) < 0 Then _
                            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=("INACTIVE"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

                Next a

            End With

        Next w

    End With

End Sub
```

Currently, when I run this code, everything works great up until this line:

```
.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=("INACTIVE"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

I get the error:

> Named argument not found

Comment: You know, you don't have to activate the workbooks in order to insert those rows? You can turn `wkbk1.Activate / ws2.Activate / Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert` into just `ws2.Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert`

Comment: You are trying to use AutoFilter as a Range property but not specifying a range.

Comment: @jamheadart Thank you for the help. I knew that code was unnecessary and was going to change it, but thank you for a neat solution to it :)

Comment: @SJR The thing is, not every sheet has the header "Status" so I cant specify Range("B:B") for example.

Comment: So test first whether Status is found, using Find or Match.

Comment: Thank you @SJR, Xabier has provided a solution with that function :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@EitelDagnin you should first use .Find to see if the header exists and then use the AutoFilter, something like:

```
Set StatusFound = Worksheets(w).Rows(1).Find(What:="Status", LookAt:=xlWhole)
'Above search for the Word "Status" on the first row of the Sheet

If NOT StatusFound is Nothing then
'''''If Status is found then
'''''Apply your filter

    For a = .Columns.count To 1 Step -1
        If UBound(Filter(filterCols, Worksheets(w).Cells(1, a), True, vbTextCompare)) < 0 Then _
            Worksheets(w).UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=StatusFound.Column, Criteria1:=("INACTIVE"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        End If
    Next a
End if
```